# Do I use italics on subsequent occurrences of this word?

Tags: italics

I'm writing a formal essay about the Greek concept of *xenia*. I know I have to italicize it, but when I use this word in subsequent sentences and paragraphs, do I still italicize it? Or is it fine to leave it as I italicized it at the beginning already?

Comment: As far as I know it is not a word that has become part of the English language, so I would italicise it every time.

Comment: I'm writing in MLA format.

Comment: Why would it change? If it needed italics in the first instance, why would it not need them throughout, please?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what style guide you are using. For example, if you're going to be using the word a lot, the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/NoneoftheAbove.html) says only the first occurrence should be italicized:

> CMOS 7.49. Italics at first occurrence: "If a foreign word becomes familiar through repeated use throughout a work, it need be italicized only on its first occurrence. If it appears only rarely, however, italics may be retained."

Comment: I'm writing in MLA format.